# Vagrant GUI non-alphanumeric key bindings incorrect

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I am starting to use Vagrant to stand up a development environment(want to ensure all teammates are developing on same environment) and seeing as it will be a development environment, I need it to have a GUI enabled. I decided to go with the box "pussinboots/ubuntu-truly-full" since that seemed to be the only(or first) 14.04 non-server box.

I got that up and running fine, but it seems like the key bindings are messed up. For instance, when I type the '/' character, '-' shows up in the ubuntu box. Not all of the key bindings are messed up, and this is only when I am typing inside of VirtualBox(vagrant ssh'ing into the machine and typing in that terminal yields the correct characters). Rather new to this line of stuff, so not even sure where to begin looking.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue in "pussinboots/ubuntu-truly-full" box(not sure). Best solution is create your own custom box(as requirement needs). You can enable GUI by modifying Vagrantfile.

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.gui = true
end
```